# Networkx graph does not hold its value

Tags: python, networkx

I have been working with this Python piece of code:

```
import networkx as nx
import random
import copy

iteracoes = 10
topologia = nx.gnp_random_graph(N,1.0)

def escolha_contatos(g):
    contatos = [] 
    n_contatos = g.number_of_edges() 

    while (n_contatos > 0):
        contatos.append(random.choice(g.edges())) 
        g.remove_node(contatos[-1][0]) #remocao do nodo da rede
        g.remove_node(contatos[-1][1]) #remocao do nodo da rede
        n_contatos = g.number_of_edges() #novo numero de contatos

    return contatos

for i in range(1,iteracoes):
    aux_top = copy.copy(topologia)
    contatos = escolha_contatos(aux_top)
```

Where `topologia` is a graph. When I call the function `escolha_contatos`, this function changes the topologia's number of edges. This result is not interesting for me. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `copy.copy` only makes a shallow copy, meaning the data structures storing the nodes and edges are not copied.  Use `copy.deepcopy(topologia)` to make a deep copy of the graph.

Comment: Wow! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much. I just have one question: is there any rule I should follow to decide whether to use `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy`?

Comment: @EnockNeto: `copy.copy` only copies the object you give it, not any other objects that object may reference.  `copy.deepcopy` copies (or tries to copy) recursively everything referenced by the object you give it.  Read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) for more info.

Comment: Ok. I'll read the documentation to avoid these kind of problem. Thank you again.